# Why are these two identical sets of Firebase rules are working very differently?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This set of rules is working fine and giving output as expected

```
{
"rules": {
  "intents" : {
    ".read" : "auth.uid === data.child('to').val()",
    ".write" : true
  },
  "messages" : {
    ".read":  "auth.uid !== null",
    "$message": {
           ".write": true
    }
  }
}
}
```

But, this set of rules is not allowing any user to read any data, though write operation is working fine in this set too.

```
{
"rules": {
  "intents" : {
    ".read" : "auth.uid === data.child('to').val()",
    ".write" : true
  },
  "messages" : {
    "$message": {
           ".read":  "auth.uid !== null",
           ".write": true
    }
  }
}
}
```

To me, both these sets look almost identical. Is there any "Firebase security rules" rule which I'm missing?
**NOTE** Both these rules were tested without making any change to the database or any code. Only the rules shown were altered.

Comment: [Security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters);

Answer (score 2):

The two sets of rules have one important difference: The first one allows to read "messages" in one operation, while the other allows only to read any single message at once. You are probably trying to read all messages in one operation, only the first rules will let you do that.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "messages" : {
      ".read":  "auth.uid !== null", // Here: Can read all at once
      "$message": {
        ".read":  "auth.uid !== null", // Here: Can only read one at a time
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using a recyclerviewadapter in android to read the messages. But in the second case, I'm not able to read even one message, although in the first case, the app is working fine and showing all messages properly.

Comment: I've never heard of recyclerviewadapter. How does it get the messages for you? Are you sure it doesn't try to read all the messages?

Comment: Even if it reads all the messages at once, shouldn't it display at least one message as in case 2 as said by you?

Comment: No, in the second case you can only read messages if you try to read that message directly. E.g. you could read from`ref.(child).('messages').child(messageId)`, but not from `ref.child('messages')`. When searching from the root up to and including 'messages', there is no `.read` rule to permit the read.

Comment: So, how do I read the messages the way I want to? i.e. initially, all the existing messages and then one by one when new messages arrive in the database.

Comment: Just use the first version of the security rules?

Comment: Did you mean the first case I have mentioned in the question or the first version of the firebase service?

Comment: The first version/set of rules in your question, that "is working fine and giving output as expected".

Comment: Sir, but the problem with the first case is that every user can read every other user's message. The rule I applied in the above sets were just for representation, the actual motive is applying 'user based security'. If the above rules would have worked, I would have replaced them with uid based rules as described in firebase documentation.

Comment: This seems like a new problem, maybe ask a new question to get help to solve it.